# No Database selected SQLException using Datasource

Tags: java, mysql, datasource

I have created a webapp using servlets. I am establishing a connection to a `MySQL` `database` using a `DataSource` object and get the following stacktrace when I load the webpage:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
    at uk.co.morleys.TestimonialService.countTestimonials(TestimonialService.java:106)
    at uk.co.morleys.TestimonialService.getPaginationDetails(TestimonialService.java:122)
    at uk.co.morleys.HomeController.doGet(HomeController.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the TestimonialService.java file:

```
public class TestimonialService {
    ResultSet rs;
    DataSource ds;

    public TestimonialService(){
        rs = null;
        ds = DataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();
    }
    public int countTestimonials() throws SQLException{
        int count = 0;
        try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()){
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM morleys_testimonial WHERE isActive=1");
            while(rs.next()){
                count = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

This is the DataSourceFactory.java where I establish a connection to the database:

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

    public static DataSource getMySQLDataSource() {
        MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = null;
        try {
            mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();
            mysqlDS.setURL("jdbc:mysql://hostname/");
            mysqlDS.setDatabaseName("dbname");
            mysqlDS.setUser("user");
            mysqlDS.setPassword("password");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return mysqlDS;
    }
}
```

**Question** Am I not selecting the database with `setDatabaseName()`? If not how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont you simply try this

```
mysqlDS.setURL("jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname");
```

instead of

```
mysqlDS.setDatabaseName("dbname");
```

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! Unsure why the other way didn't work if the relevant method is provided though?

Answer (score 1):

Are you providing port number along with the hostname? If not try giving portnumber as well.
Additionally make sure you have Mysql JDBC Driver
You can follow any of these tutorial for creating MysqlDataSource:

http://www.journaldev.com/2509/jdbc-datasource-example-oracle-mysql-and-apache-dbcp-tutorial

or

http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/MySQL-JDBC-Driver-DataSource.html